# How do I prove that the del squared operator commutes with the angular momentum operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, operators, commutator

I need to prove in Cartesian coordinates that $[\nabla^{2},\hat{L_{z}}]= 0$

I know that the angular momentum operator is defined as:

$\hat{L_{z}}=x\hat{p_{y}}-y\hat{p_{x}}$

And the del squared is the partial derivatives:

$\nabla^{2}={<\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}},\frac{d^{2}}{dy^{2}},\frac{d^{2}}{dz^{2}}>}$

I think I'm essentially supposed to show

$\nabla^{2}\hat{L_{z}}= \hat{L_{z}}\nabla^{2}$

I'm not quite sure if that's the right approach. If it is, I'm not sure how to do that without just saying the second derivative of x and y are both zero.

Comment: Compute $\nabla^2 {\hat L}_z f(x,y,z)$ where $f$ is any function. Then compute ${\hat L}_z \nabla^2 f(x,y,z)$. Show that both answers are the same. QED.

Comment: Doesn't $\nabla^{2}\hat{L_{z}}= 0$?

Comment: Why do you think so??

Comment: $\nabla^{2}\hat{L_{z}}={\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}[x\hat{p_{y}}]-\frac{d^{2}}{dy^{2}}[y\hat{p_{x}}] = 0 - 0 = 0}$ Or is that not how that works?

Comment: That is not how it works. I am not asking you to compute $(\nabla^2 {\hat L}_z) f(x,y,z)$. I am asking you to compute $\nabla^2 \left( {\hat L}_z f(x,y,z) \right)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's what a commutator is.  Remember that the momentum operator is $\vec p = -i\hbar\vec\nabla$, so $\nabla^2 = -p^2/\hbar^2$; also that $\nabla^2$ is a *scalar*, not a vector.

Usually when you find a commutator you need a "test function" for the operators to operate on; that's how you find for instance that $[\hat x, \hat p_x]=+i\hbar$.

Comment: How does that momentum operator work in our three dimensions? The problem I'm having is multiplying (dimensionless momentum) by $\hat{p_{x}}$ and $\hat{p_{y}}$

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "dimensionless momentum." But $\hat p_x = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ commutes with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and also (for physically interesting functions) with  $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ whether it has the right units for momentum or not.

Answer (score 2):

> I think I'm essentially supposed to show...

Why do you think this? Is this a homework question? If so then it should be tagged as such.

If this is not a homework question and you are interested to read an explanation involving no explicit equations then consider the following:

The operator $\vec L$ is the generator of rotations. Therefore, any rotationally invariant operator must commute with $\vec L$. The operator $\nabla^2$ is the square of a vector $\vec \nabla$. The square of a vector is rotationally invariant. Therefore $\nabla^2$ is rotationally invariant and therefore must commute with $\vec L$. Since each Cartesian component of $\vec L$ is independent, $\nabla^2$ must commute with each of $L_x$, $L_y$, and $L_z$ individually.

Boom. *drops mic*. *walks off stage*.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume $\hbar = 1$

We have the following expression for the commutator
$$ [\nabla^2, L_z] = -[p^2, L_z] = -[p_x^2 + p_y^2 + p_z^2, L_z]$$
Now using the fact that the action of the commutator is linear we can write
$$ [p_x^2 + p_y^2 + p_z^2, L_z] = [p_x^2, L_z] + [p_y^2, L_z] + [p_z^2, L_z]$$
Now I'm going to use the property
$$ [AC, B] = A[C, B] + [A, B]C $$
for each terms in the right hand side, so we have
$$[p_x^2, L_z] = [p_x p_x, L_z] = p_x[p_x, L_z] + [p_x, L_z]p_x $$
and a similar expression for the other two terms.

Now to evalute the commutators left we'll use the definition of $L_z$ in terms of impulse and position
$$ L_z = x p_y - y p_x $$
and we'll consider the fact the operators that acts on different spaces commute, which means
$$ [x_i, p_j ] = \delta_{ij} ~~~~~  [x_i, x_j ] = 0 ~~~~~ [p_i, p_j ] = 0$$
where the index $i$ (and $j$) identify the $i$'s components of $\vec{x}$ (and $j$'s of $\vec{p}$).

Now you have all the ingredients to obtain
$$[\nabla^2, L_z] = 0 $$